# Using PyAV to generate audio broadcast server (UDP socket)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp, alsa, pyav

I have to create a service which captures the audio from the PC microphone and to broadcast it as UDP packets. I am on a Debian platform and I have to use Python (3.7).

I would like to use [PyAV](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV) because I have to link this broadcasting system to a local custom WebRTC service using [aiortc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc), which relies on PyAV.

I have to do this because I cannot access the same audio source (ALSA) from several processes (RTC peers), so I was thinking to create a UDP broacasting system in a localhost environment. Is this the best practice? Have you any other idea?

I have noticed [here](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/issues/325) that with the call: `av.open("udp://xxx:nnn", format="alsa")` I should be able to receive audio UDP packets, but I am not sure how to generate a UDP server which captures from the mic and sends the UDP packets, so, how to create the server side of this implementation? In particular, I managed to capture the audio with: `av.open("hw:0", format="alsa")`, how can I send the captured buffer over UDP sockets?

Comment: you can try with icecast2